# CameraPreview on Camera plugin for flutter always crash (not working)

Tags: android, image, flutter, camera, crash

I have project that using camera, and I am a newbie for flutter.
I already tried copy paste all the code here [enter link description here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/plugins/picture-using-camera), but never work, always crash with this log:

```
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
Abort message: '[FATAL:flutter/shell/platform/android/platform_view_android_jni.cc(123)] Check failed: CheckException(env).
'
    rax 0000000000000000  rbx 00007f07ee38b500  rcx ffffffffffffffff  rdx 0000000000000006
    rsi 000000000000170f  rdi 00000000000016fa
    r8  0000000000000003  r9  0000000000000003  r10 0000000000000008  r11 0000000000000206
    r12 000000000000170f  r13 0000000000000006  r14 00007f07ee389708  r15 00007f08002c78f4
    cs  0000000000000033  ss  000000000000002b
    rip 00007f0804f2aa67  rbp 0000000000000000  rsp 00007f07ee389668  eflags 0000000000000206
backtrace:
    #00 pc 0000000000087a67  /system/lib64/libc.so (tgkill+7)
    #01 pc 0000000000085b11  /system/lib64/libc.so (pthread_kill+65)
    #02 pc 000000000002e841  /system/lib64/libc.so (raise+17)
    #03 pc 00000000000288fd  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+61)
```

When I try to debug, the problem is on "CameraPreview(_controller)" widget.

Any helps will be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: maybe you didn't do the requirements to work with this plugin check this link https://pub.dev/packages/camera

Comment: maybe you can list 1 by 1 the steps? because I already read that link multiple times and still cant figure it out.